# getting error while trying to compile code for soil moisture sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, arduino-ide

I think the below logic should work but its throwing error

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int soil_moisture = analogRead(A0); // read from analog pin A3
//  int soil_moisture = pinMode(AO);
  Serial.print(“analog value: “);
  if (soil_moisture < 30) {
    Serial.println(“Dry soil”);
  }
  if ((soil_moisture > 300) && (soil_moisture < 700)) {
    Serial.println(“Humid soil”);
  }
  if ((soil_moisture > 700) && (soil_moisture < 950)) {
    Serial.println(“water”);
  }
}
```

error i get is

```
Arduino: 1.6.12 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:16: error: stray '\342' in program
   Serial.print(“analog value: “);
   ^
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:16: error: stray '\200' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:16: error: stray '\234' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:16: error: stray '\342' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:16: error: stray '\200' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:16: error: stray '\234' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:18: error: stray '\342' in program
     Serial.println(“Dry soil”);
     ^
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:18: error: stray '\200' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:18: error: stray '\234' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:18: error: stray '\342' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:18: error: stray '\200' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:18: error: stray '\235' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:21: error: stray '\342' in program
     Serial.println(“Humid soil”);
     ^
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:21: error: stray '\200' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:21: error: stray '\234' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:21: error: stray '\342' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:21: error: stray '\200' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:21: error: stray '\235' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:24: error: stray '\342' in program
     Serial.println(“water”);
     ^
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:24: error: stray '\200' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:24: error: stray '\234' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:24: error: stray '\342' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:24: error: stray '\200' in program
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:24: error: stray '\235' in program
/Users/ciastro/Documents/Arduino/analog_soil_moisture_v01/analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino/analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino.ino: In function 'void loop()':
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:16: error: 'analog' was not declared in this scope
   Serial.print(“analog value: “);
                   ^
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:18: error: 'Dry' was not declared in this scope
     Serial.println(“Dry soil”);
                       ^
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:21: error: 'Humid' was not declared in this scope
     Serial.println(“Humid soil”);
                       ^
analog_soil_moisture_v02.ino:24: error: 'water' was not declared in this scope
     Serial.println(“water”);
                       ^
exit status 1
stray '\342' in program

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you declared NONE of your variables (`int`, `float`s) (except `soil_moisture`)

You must declare them. This is not Python where you can simply name a variable without declaring its type. Arduino language is based on C/C++.

Comment: Where did you get that Arduino language comes from JavaScript? I have known C and C++ for over 20 years, JavaScript for about 10 years and I don't see where Arduino language could be based on the latter.

Comment: My bad, its Java (not JavaScript). It's actually the function printf() from Java which translates to Serial.print(F())

Comment: `printf` is initially a standard C function, long before Java.

Answer (score 3):

The actual error you are seeing is caused by the use of incorrect quotes in your program. You most likely copied and pasted the code from a website which has replaced the proper quotes with typeset-standard quotes:

```
    Serial.println(“Humid soil”);
```

should be:

```
    Serial.println("Humid soil");
```

Note the subtle difference in the quite shape. The first set are typesetter's open- and close-quote characters. The latter are just plain double-quotes (shift-2 on a UK keyboard).

There are other special characters in your program that need replacing with the standard ASCII equivalent, as well.